# Php formulae to calculate new lat long position to specific distance

Tags: php, google-maps, gis

I have a Latitude and longitude points. Now i need to move them say 0.25 miles to any direction in map. I am using google maps. I want to do this in php. Reason I want this is to not pinpoint accurately to user submitted address instead scramble few distance away. Is there any algorithm available for this kind of task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping I haven't missed any brackets

```
$fromLatitude = 51.5171;
$fromLongitude = -0.1062;

echo $fromLatitude, ' - ', $fromLongitude, PHP_EOL;

$distanceInMetres = 250;
$bearing = 0;

    $earthMeanRadius = 6371009.0; // metres

    $destinationLatitude = rad2deg(
        asin(
            sin(deg2rad($fromLatitude)) *
                cos($distanceInMetres / $earthMeanRadius) +
            cos(deg2rad($fromLatitude)) *
                sin($distanceInMetres / $earthMeanRadius) *
                cos(deg2rad($bearing))
        )
    );
    $destinationLongitude = rad2deg(
        deg2rad($fromLongitude) +
        atan2(
            sin(deg2rad($bearing)) *
                sin($distanceInMetres / $earthMeanRadius) *
                cos(deg2rad($fromLatitude)),
            cos($distanceInMetres / $earthMeanRadius) -
                sin(deg2rad($fromLatitude)) * sin(deg2rad($destinationLatitude))
        )
    );

echo $destinationLatitude, ' - ', $destinationLongitude, PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute delta Lat and delta Lon. One latitude is always 111km and the longitude is also 111km over the equator and everywhere else smaller. The length of 1° longitude depends on the latitude. There is a formula on Wikipedia.

Answer (score -2):

You can find a simple JavaScript implementation right here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

You'll need to scroll down to "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point" and there you will find a JavaScript on how do it. You do however need the bearing as a parameter to the formula. I am sorry that it isn't a PHP implementation, but I guess it can be converted.

```
<!-- use this to use the Geo object -->
<script src="http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geo.js"></script>
<script>
  function orthoDestMap() {
    // eg. 53°19′14″N
    var lat1 = Geo.parseDMS($('#ortho-dest .lat1').val());

    // eg. 001°43′47″W
    var lon1 = Geo.parseDMS($('#ortho-dest .lon1').val());

    // eg. 096°01′18″
    var brng = Geo.parseDMS($('#ortho-dest .brng').val());

    // In kilometers
    var dist = 111;

    var p1 = new LatLon(lat1, lon1);
    var p2 = p1.destinationPoint(brng, dist);

    // New latitude and longitude
    lat2 = p2.lat();
    lon2 = p2.lon();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes i want to get new lat long which is say x miles distance from current lat long in any direction